# Same page giving diferent visual output

Tags: css

I have this **.html** file and that form, sometimes stretches across all width. Tested with Opera, Firefox and Edge.


 **.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>LOGIN</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-teal.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="w3-card-4 form">
      <form class="w3-container" action="/login" method="post">
        <label for="username">Nome de utilizador</label>
        <input class="w3-input" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nome de utilizador" required id="username">
        <label for="password">Password</label>1
        <input class="w3-input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required id="username">
        <button class="w3-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**style.css file:**

```
.big {
    background: rgb(150, 150, 150);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 40vw;
    max-height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.lightgray {
    background-color:#c5c5c5!important;
}

.bordergray {
    border-color:#6e6e6e!important;
}

.rightalign {
    float: right !important;
}

.form {
    width: 50vw;
    /*margin-left: 2vw;*/
}

body {font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif}
.w3-bar-block .w3-bar-item {
  padding: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I can say that it is CSS fault, but I don´t know what or how a rule could be causing this.
This HTML was generated by compiling a .pug file, so I don't have a pretty version of it, feel free to edit this question if you could format the HTML.

EDIT:
Sometimes I get IMG1, others I get IMG2 but only if I open a new tab, why?
**IMG1**
[image: IMG1]
**IMG2:**
[image: IMG2]
(I set the background color to black, so its more visible the size of the fields)

Comment: Which browser is behaving differently than the others?

Comment: @DonkeyShame Every one is giving the same random behaviour

Comment: what is `assets/js/index.js` doing?

Comment: @zgood The index.js file is doing nothing in this page and can be removed without any conflicts, I already tested removing it and does not affect this particular page.

Comment: So, all the browsers are displaying the content in the same way?

Comment: @DonkeyShame Yes, they are displaying the content randomly

Comment: Not sure I can help unless you elaborate on what it means for *all* the browsers to display the content *randomly*. What precisely does that mean?

Comment: I tested in Edge and Chrome and Edge Canary; other than some user agent idiosyncracies, it looks like they display identically to me. What is the random part?

Comment: @DonkeyShame I updated the question

Comment: Is it on mobile and having its width set for portait, and then you are turning it landscape?, Just having a guess by the aspects ratios of your images.

Comment: I've now tested the provided code in Firefox, Edge, Edge Canary, and Chrome. In all cases, the form displays at 50% of the viewport width. I'm not sure how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanks for all the help, but further debugging show me that the file style.css was not being imported, so I changed

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
```

and works all the time, thanks for all the help.